# Solving USB hub failure issues without reboot

Tags: 16.04, usb, udev

There is an internal usb hub failure message storm in dmesg in my Ubuntu 16.04LTS machine.

I tried to restart udev using the following command, but it didnt solve my problem.

```
sudo systemctl restart udev.service
```

Rebooting the machine should solve the problem, i had it this error message and rebooting worked for me. But, i do not want to reboot it.

Is there a way to solve this issue without reboot my Linux machine?

```
[1450314.465689] hub 4-2:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -71)
[1450314.469189] hub 4-2:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -71)
[1450314.472697] hub 4-2:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -71)
[1450314.476190] hub 4-2:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -71)
[1450314.479689] hub 4-2:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -71)
[1450314.483190] hub 4-2:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -71)
[1450314.504190] hub 4-2:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -71)
[1450314.507713] hub 4-2:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -71)
[1450314.511206] hub 4-2:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -71)
```

Comment: One of your USB devices may be causing this error message. Unplug one or more USB devices and see if the messages stop.

Comment: I was suspecting from a device and just disconnected that but didnt solve. After your message, I disconnected all devices and connected them back, and the warning message storming stopped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**From the comments...**

One of your USB devices may be causing this error message. Unplug one or more USB devices and see if the messages stop.

**Update #1:**

Disconnected all USB devices and connected back, warning message storming stopped.

Answer (score 1):

I do have this problem a lot with my USB card, from lspci, it is a
`b3:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM2142/ASM3142 USB 3.1 Host Controller`

When it does start outputting these kind of messages, I run the script and it temporarily fixes it until it happens again.

Here is what I get in journalctl -k

> Jan 03 12:58:34 p4 kernel: hub 6-2.4:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed
> (err = -110)
> Jan 03 12:58:39 p4 kernel: usb 6-2.4.1: Failed to suspend
> device, error -110
> Jan 03 12:58:47 p4 kernel: hub 6-2.4:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -110)
> Jan 03 12:58:51 p4 kernel: retire_capture_urb: 3 callbacks suppressed
> Jan 03 12:58:52 p4 kernel: usb 6-2.4.1: Failed to suspend device, error -110 
> Jan 03 12:58:56 p4 kernel: hub 5-2:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -110)

Here is the script to reset the USB devices:

❯ cat /usr/local/bin/reset_usb

```
#!/bin/bash
[ `id -u` -ne 0 ] && exec sudo "$0"
cd /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd
#BUS="0000:18:00.0"
BUS="0000:b3:00.0"
echo "$BUS" > unbind
sleep 5
echo "$BUS" > bind
sleep 5
find "$BUS/" -name control -exec /bin/sh -c "echo on > {}" \;
```

The way I found I should put `BUS="0000:b3:00.0"` is by looking at dmesg and checking `ls -l /sys/bus/usb/devices/` to find the PCI bus the USB device attaches too.  Such as `usb 6-2.4.1: Failed to suspend` I check for 6-2*.

> ❯ ls -ld /sys/bus/usb/devices/6-2*
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  3
> 12:59 /sys/bus/usb/devices/**6-2** ->
> ../../../devices/pci0000:b2/**0000:b2:00.0/0000:b3:00.0**/usb6/6-2

Then I see it is either the PCI device `0000:b2:00.0` or `0000:b3:00.0`.  Then I check in the xhci_hci drivers which one should be removed:

> ❯ ls -ld /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/0000*
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  3 11:11 /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/0000:00:14.0 ->
> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0
> Jan  3 11:11 /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/**0000:03:00.0** ->
> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:03:00.0
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  3 12:59 /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/0000:b3:00.0 ->
> ../../../../devices/pci0000:b2/0000:b2:00.0/0000:b3:00.0

In this case, `0000:b3:00.0` is the right device to put in the BUS driver.  You can then run the script, type in your sudo password, and all your USB devices will reconnect in about 10 seconds.